# How do I add following missing references in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am new to .net and VS 2019, recently I was transitioned a .net code which I need to run in my system. Initially got several reference issues but I was able to solve them by installing the respective NuGets in VS 2019. However I am not able to resolve the following reference issues, without resolving these I get build errors. Can anyone please guide me in resolving this. I have mentioned the reference names that I need also attached the screenshot.

I'm using Visual Studio version 2019and .net Framework 4.6.1

Reference Names-

1. VBIDE
2. WordnetClasses
3. WordNetControls

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Did you add the "using" statement at top of module?   Is the error on the using statement or on a line of code?

Comment: If I use the using statement also, it says "unused  reference"... right now I have error on line of code. And these are all assembly references.